# Listening to a variable change in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to listen to a variable change to execute some code. So the variable is a bool named `reset`. I want to execute something (say reset the animation controller) once the animation ends OR a button (from another widget) is pressed. Executing something when the animation ends works as once it ends `AnimationStatus.dismissed` will be its state and the listener will be called. This then allows me to use a callback function `onCountdownexpire` in order to set the variable `reset` accordingly and based on what it is set, execute some code in the `if(widget.reset)` block. So there is no need to listen for this case.

***Problem:***

However, lets say a button is pressed (in another widget) and I set the variable `reset` to true. I want the animation to stop and reset. I cannot now depend on the `AnimationStatus` listener as it only executes **when** there is a state change. I want it to reset during its state. So I have to somehow listen to the variable `widget.reset`.

I have done some research on this and found out that `ValueNotifier` might be a way to go but there are not a lot of examples on how to go about using it. Like how do I go about listening to it ?

Code:

```dart
class Countdown extends StatefulWidget {

  final VoidCallback onCountdownExpire;
  bool reset;
  Countdown(this.onCountdownExpire);

  @override
  CountdownState createState() => CountdownState();
}

class CountdownState extends State<Countdown> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;

  String get timerString {
    Duration duration = controller.duration * controller.value;
    return '${duration.inMinutes}:${(duration.inSeconds % 60).toString()}';
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
    )..addStatusListener((AnimationStatus status){
        if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
          debugPrint("Animation.dismissed");
          widget.onCountdownExpire();
          if (widget.reset) {
            widget.reset = false;
            controller.reverse(from: 1.0);
          } 
        }
    });
    controller.reverse(from: 1.0);
  }
  ... // omitted code
}
```

What I have tried but it does not seem to be working as expected:

```dart
class Countdown extends StatefulWidget {

  final VoidCallback onCountdownExpire;
  Countdown(this.onCountdownExpire);
  ValueNotifier reset = ValueNotifier(false);

  @override
  CountdownState createState() => CountdownState();
}

class CountdownState extends State<Countdown> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {

    widget.reset.addListener(() {
      debugPrint("value notifier is true");
      controller.reverse(from: 1.0);
    });

    super.initState();

    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
    )..addStatusListener((AnimationStatus status){
        if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
          debugPrint("Animation.dismissed");
          widget.onCountdownExpire();
        }
    });
    controller.reverse(from: 1.0);
  }
  ... // omitted code
}
```

**Update: The solution (above) was actually working, I just had to use something like this to notify the listener:**

```dart
countdown.reset.notifyListeners();
// OR
countdown.reset.value = true;
```

Comment: use `ValueNotifier::addListener` method

Comment: @pskink Ok hi, I tried that but it does not seem to be working as expected (post updated). Am I implementing it correctly ?

Comment: @pskink ok nvm i was calling it wrongly, I had to use something like `countdown.reset.notifyListeners(); `. Thanks for your help ! Post your answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: no, you dont need `notifyListeners` - if you call `countdown.reset = ...` the method `notifyListeners` will be called automagically - see `ValueNotifier` docs: *"When `value` is replaced with something that is not equal to the old value as evaluated by the equality operator ==, this class notifies its listeners."*

Comment: @pskink hmmm I tried `countdown.reset = ValueNotifier(true)` but it did not seem to update

Comment: sorry, i mean `countdown.reset.value = ...`

Comment: @pskink ah its working now too (after I did `countdown.reset.value = true`). Thanks man !

Comment: sure, your welcome

Comment: If I do it like a this, I get warning: "must_be_immutable" for Countdown class, since it extends StatefulWidget which is immutable.

Answer (score 28):

*OP already got an answer in the comments. I'm just typing it here so the question is correctly marked as answered.*

Just notify the listener:

```
countdown.reset.notifyListeners();
// OR
countdown.reset.value = true;
```

Credit to @pskink

Comment: thanks thats work for me

Answer (score 0):

### Use of overwriting getter/setters

You can make use of the **getter and setter functions**.

In the example below we are printing happy birthday w*hen the person's age changes*:

```
class Person {
  int _age;

  Person(this._age);

  int get age => _age;
  
  set age(int newValue) {
    print("Happy birthday! You have a new Age.");
    //do some awsome things here when the age changes
    _age = newValue;
  }
}
```

The usage is exactly as you are used to:

```
final newPerson = Person(20);
  
print(newPerson.age); //20
newPerson.age = 21; //prints happy birthday
print(newPerson.age); //21
```

Comment: @KristiJorgji It's technically not "listening".  But it has the same outcome, and sometimes even is more suitable for certain situations that might be searched up by "listening to variable change". I would say at least a considerable answer...

Comment: Yes it is true that it is not listening, but it does what the question owner asked to do. But I get it now makes sense why it got downvoted as he asked "listen" there is no listener or notifier mechanism in this solution but it is an imperative approach