# How to listen to variable changes in a provider class?

Tags: flutter, dart

When using providers, how can I listen to a value change in the provider class?
In the code below, when `_myData` changes, I want to change `_allData` as well. (I know I can just change them both together, but the code below is a stripped version of what I have)

```dart
class CoolProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<String> _allData = [];
  List<String> _myData = [];

  List<OrdersResponse> get allData => _allData;
  List<OrdersResponse> get myData => _myData;

  void changeData()  {
      _allData = ['yo', 'bro'];
      notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: @BeHappy Same. I did it on friday!

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71295321/11003497) answer. Where the **getter/setter method** is being overwritten.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `addListener` for instance of your class.

```dart
CoolProvider coolProvider = CoolProvider();

void f() {
 // access new data
}

coolProvider.addListener(f);
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to listen to `_myData` is it the same idea?

Comment: then you can access new data in callback function.